# how do i make my grid view be visible completely without having it be scrollable?

Tags: flutter, dart

how do i make my grid view be visible completely without it having be scrollable. if there are many elements i want the body to be scrollable not the grid.
i have attached few images of what my code looks like now and how id like it to look

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:urban_harvest1/steps.dart';
import 'package:urban_harvest1/landing/plantlist.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(
              'What do you want to grow today?',
            ),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60),
              child: SearchBar(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return const Color(0xFF6290C3);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: searchResults(searchString: 'i')),
    );
  }
}

class plantCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String plantName;
  const plantCard({super.key, required this.plantName});

  @override
  State<plantCard> createState() => _plantCardState();
}

class _plantCardState extends State<plantCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.plantName),
    );
  }
}

class categoryCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String categoryName;
  final List<Widget> plantWidgets;
  const categoryCard(
      {super.key, required this.categoryName, required this.plantWidgets});
  @override
  State<categoryCard> createState() => _categoryCardState();
}

class _categoryCardState extends State<categoryCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(widget.categoryName),
          Flexible(
            child: GridView.count(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: widget.plantWidgets,),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class searchResults extends StatefulWidget {
  final String searchString;
  const searchResults({super.key, required this.searchString});
  @override
  State<searchResults> createState() => _searchResultsState();
}

class _searchResultsState extends State<searchResults> {
  late List<Widget> plantCategoryList;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    plantCategoryList = [];
    var searchQueryResults1 = searchQueryResults(widget.searchString);
    for (var i in searchQueryResults1.keys) {
      List<Widget> plantList = [];
      for (int a = 0; a < searchQueryResults1[i]!.length; ++a) {
        plantList.add(plantCard(plantName: searchQueryResults1[i]![a]));
      }
      plantCategoryList
          .add(categoryCard(categoryName: i, plantWidgets: plantList));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: plantCategoryList,
    );
  }
}
```

[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p5at.png)
[What i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed0Cj.png)
i am new to flutter. please help

i tried a few solutions but it throws so many errors like RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout, finally i have this code but the grid view is scrollable and not visible completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directly wrapped the Column with Column widget.
wrapped the whole body with Single child scroll to make the page scrollable and in category builder wrapped GridView.count directly inside the Column without using Expanded. it works as you intended now

````dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testing/plantlist.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'What do you want to grow today?',
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60),
          child: SearchBar(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                return const Color(0xFF6290C3);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(child: searchResults(searchString: 'i')),
    ));
  }
}

class plantCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String plantName;

  const plantCard({super.key, required this.plantName});

  @override
  State<plantCard> createState() => _plantCardState();
}

class _plantCardState extends State<plantCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 100, // Adjust the height as needed
            width: 100, // Adjust the width as needed
            child: Placeholder(color: Colors.black), // Sample black box
          ),
          Text(widget.plantName),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class categoryCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String categoryName;
  final List<Widget> plantWidgets;

  const categoryCard(
      {super.key, required this.categoryName, required this.plantWidgets});

  @override
  State<categoryCard> createState() => _categoryCardState();
}


class _categoryCardState extends State<categoryCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(widget.categoryName),
        GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: widget.plantWidgets,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class searchResults extends StatefulWidget {
  final String searchString;

  const searchResults({super.key, required this.searchString});

  @override
  State<searchResults> createState() => _searchResultsState();
}

class _searchResultsState extends State<searchResults> {
  late List<Widget> plantCategoryList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    plantCategoryList = [];
    var searchQueryResults1 = searchQueryResults(widget.searchString);
    for (var i in searchQueryResults1.keys) {
      List<Widget> plantList = [];
      for (int a = 0; a < searchQueryResults1[i]!.length; ++a) {
        plantList.add(plantCard(plantName: searchQueryResults1[i]![a]));
      }
      plantCategoryList
          .add(categoryCard(categoryName: i, plantWidgets: plantList));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: plantCategoryList,
    );
  }
}
```\
````